# User object syntax in status post array

Tags: facebook, object

What is the syntax for referencing a specific user object in the status post array with the Facebook API?  Below is what I have already.

```
$status = $facebook->api('/<PAGE_ID>/feed', 'POST', array(
'from' =>       "id": "<PAGE_ID>", "name": "<PAGE_NAME>",
'title' =>  'This is the title',
'message' =>    'This is the message',
'description'=> 'This is the description',
'caption' =>    'This is the caption',
'link' => 'http://www.thisisthelink.com'
));
```

Everything works except the FROM field.

Comment: `'from' =>       "id": "<PAGE_ID>", "name": "<PAGE_NAME>",` <---- what is it?! It is not even a valid php syntax

Comment: I don't see `from` property on the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts either

Comment: The `from` code is referring to the user object in a _post_.  I realize the above is not valid PHP syntax; I'm not going to publicly post the profile ID that I'm working on.

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: Well, somewhat nonsense.  But that's why I'm here big guy.

Your response below helps clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/<PAGE_ID>/feed` doesn't accept `from` parameter, only parameters from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts are available to specify.

See also: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/691425/251311

Answer (score 0):

This works.  I was confusing the parameters of a post with that of the feed.

```
<?

require_once 'fb_access.php';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = '****NOT*PHP*CODE*PLACEHOLDER*FOR*PAGE*ID*DUH****';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  =>  $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       =>  'This is the message',
            'link'          =>  'http://thisisthelink',
            'caption'       =>  'This is the caption',
            'description'   =>  'This is the description',
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: So any checkmark for my answer? ;-) (which, in fact, is correct)

Comment: Sure, although I could have gone without the snarky comments.